# Convert a jQuery object into JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a jQuery object with inside value and method also. I need to convert it into JSON.

Look at the following object:

[image]

I have `self.pgrid.config.columnFields` as above screenshot.

When I have converted this object into JSON and get that JSON back to object, it is not returning `aggregateFunc` and `formatFunc`.

Look at following screenshot of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(self.pgrid.config.columnFields))`:

[image]

Here I want to get those two methods also. How can I get them?

Code of generating object is as follows:

```
this.columnFields = (config.columns || []).map(function (fieldconfig) {
    fieldconfig = ensureFieldConfig(fieldconfig);
    return createfield(self, axe.Type.COLUMNS, fieldconfig, getfield(self.allFields, fieldconfig.name));
});

function ensureFieldConfig(obj) {
    if (typeof obj === 'string') {
        return {
            name: self.captionToName(obj)
        };
    }
    return obj;
}

function createfield(rootconfig, axetype, fieldconfig, defaultfieldconfig) {
    var axeconfig;
    var fieldAxeconfig;

    if (defaultfieldconfig) {
        switch (axetype) {
            case axe.Type.ROWS:
                axeconfig = rootconfig.rowSettings;
                fieldAxeconfig = defaultfieldconfig.rowSettings;
                break;
            case axe.Type.COLUMNS:
                axeconfig = rootconfig.columnSettings;
                fieldAxeconfig = defaultfieldconfig.columnSettings;
                break;
            case axe.Type.DATA:
                axeconfig = rootconfig.dataSettings;
                fieldAxeconfig = defaultfieldconfig.dataSettings;
                break;
            default:
                axeconfig = null;
                fieldAxeconfig = null;
                break;
        }
    } else {
        axeconfig = null;
        fieldAxeconfig = null;
    }

    var merged = mergefieldconfigs(fieldconfig, fieldAxeconfig, axeconfig, defaultfieldconfig, rootconfig);

    return new Field({
        name: getpropertyvalue('name', merged.configs, ''),
        caption: getpropertyvalue('caption', merged.configs, ''),
        sort: {
            order: getpropertyvalue('order', merged.sorts, null),
            customfunc: getpropertyvalue('customfunc', merged.sorts, null)
        },
        subTotal: {
            visible: getpropertyvalue('visible', merged.subtotals, true),
            collapsible: getpropertyvalue('collapsible', merged.subtotals, true),
            collapsed: getpropertyvalue('collapsed', merged.subtotals, false) && getpropertyvalue('collapsible', merged.subtotals, true)
        },
        aggregateFuncName: getpropertyvalue('aggregateFuncName', merged.functions, 'sum'),
        aggregateFunc: getpropertyvalue('aggregateFunc', merged.functions, aggregation.sum),
        formatFunc: getpropertyvalue('formatFunc', merged.functions, null)
    }, false);
}

function getpropertyvalue(property, configs, defaultvalue) {
    for (var i = 0; i < configs.length; i++) {
        if (configs[i][property] != null) {
            return configs[i][property];
        }
    }
    return defaultvalue;
}
```

Comment: json doesn't support functions

Comment: why do you want to convert it to json,what are you doing with that json?

Comment: i want to store that object in database/localstorage .

Comment: you need to store the functions too??

Comment: create a new object with the minimum values that you need

Comment: all values are required. and i want to store that function also.

Comment: from 1 to 10 how much programming knowledge do you have?

Comment: provide the code that generated the jquery object

Comment: I can also give you live url of the website

Comment: `getpropertyvalue` how does it look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108141/discussion-between-jainish-jariwala-and-madalin-ivascu).